# How do I use require instead of import, while still being able to access properties of the variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This works

```
import { keyboard } from "@nut-tree/nut-js"
keyboard.config.autoDelayMs = 0
```

This does not

```
var keyboard = require("@nut-tree/nut-js")
keyboard.config.autoDelayMs = 0
```

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'autoDelayMs')

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first form takes the `keyboard` export (`module.exports.keyboard`), while the second form you posted takes the entire exports object and tries to set its `.config.autoDelayMs` property.

You probably want `require("@nut-tree/nut-js").keyboard`.

Comment: Holy crap, I've never seen that syntax before. I've been googling this for about 2 days, and it WORKED! thank you!

Comment: Looks you've got some reading to do, then! Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: I actually browsed that page during my searches, and its examples don't include one that looks like yours, which is how I missed it.